# Retrive data which is save in json format using mysql Query (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

M saving the data in to db using json format such as example :

```
state_id city_id
["21"]   ["32,35,67"]
```

And now want to search using mysql query(codeigniter) `where state_id = 21 AND city_id = 32`.

Can any one please help me, While googling i found one stuff "json_extract" but it's unable to know how to use it in query.

Comment: Did you even try writing a query using `json_extract`? If so show us

Comment: https://benjaminlistwon.com/blog/working-with-json-data-in-mysql-part-1-of-3/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, this is the answer:

```
$json = '{"state_id": 21, "city_id": [32,35,67]}';
$decodedJson = json_decode($json, true);

/** @var $state_id int */
/** @var $city_id array */
extract($decodedJson);

$sql = printf("SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `state_id` = %d AND `city_id` IN ( %s );", $state_id, join(',', $city_id));

echo $sql.PHP_EOL;
```

OUTPUT:

> SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `state_id` = 1 AND `city_id` IN ( 1,2,3 );

Comment: Okay, Will try the above code and update u ...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

using [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search)

```
select * from `table` where JSON_SEARCH(`city_id`, 'all', '32') IS NOT NULL;
```

for codeigniter, simply use the query function -*as i cant found another prober built-in way in codeigniter to do this*- :

```
$results = $this->db->query('select * from `table` where JSON_SEARCH(`city_id`, "all", "' . $city_id . '") IS NOT NULL;');
```